# Sitecore Security Access Rights

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have Role A. Role A is denied access to Item X.
Then there is Role B.
Role B should be granted access to Item X. 
Role B is Member of A.

So a user that is in Role A should not have Access. And a user that is in Role B should have access.

I have seen that deny cant be overwritten, is there a workaround?
I need to set the rights in code behind.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `deny`. Use breaking inheritance from `Role A`. And then allow access for `Role B`

Comment: Hi. My Role B needs to inherit all security settings from Role A, but not for Item X. Role B is a extended Role A

Answer (score 5):

You should make use of Sitecore's inheritance. On role A you can deny inheritance on role A, while allowing the access on role B.

More information on security can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assign_access_rights_to_a_security_account)